# Cordova: where and how install a plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I created a fresh new app.

Then I went to the www directory and executed `npm install cordova-plugin-file`.

And now? What must I do to work with this plugin in the app?

If I do a `cordova plugin list` it shows me only the whitelist plugin, created by default from cordova itself.

I then tried `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` and now `cordova plugin list` shows me both whitelist and file plugin.

And now? When I tried the following code I got that, on Android emulator, cordova.file is `undefined`

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) {
    console.log("got main dir", dir);
});
```

Comment: Did you wrap your code in a [deviceready event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html)?

Comment: Oh .. damn ... Yes, the whole app is wrapped into the deviceReady event handler, but ... not this code ... damn...  now it works.. 

Just a question: is it needed to do a `npm install` before the `cordova plugin add` ?

Comment: No it is not needed. Pull your plugins `cordova plugin install xxx` and then build your target platform `cordova build android` and run it `cordova run android` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was simply that  the whole app must be wrapped into the deviceReady event handler, but ... not this code ... damn... now it works

Answer (score 0):

The cordova-plugin-file plugin only work for real phone, not work for emulator.

You can install your app to your phone, and debug it.
In the console, you will get expected log.

Comment: I'm using genymotion (free for personal use), and it's emulated as a VM, so from cordova perspective is a real device. In fact, file plugin is 100% working on Genymotion emulator. But thanks a lot of the warning.